# Apache Ignite No suitable Driver

Tags: ignite

I am trying to run a sample project, which was created by downloading the project from Apache Ignite web console. I can start the server and other codes from Eclipse IDE.

When the server was started, the caches, which I created using Apache Ignite web console,  were created.

However, when I tried to run the loadCache class, I am getting:

> "No Suitable driver error"

My secret.properties file contains:

```
dsGeneric_Employees.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees
dsGeneric_Employees.jdbc.username=root
dsGeneric_Employees.jdbc.password=
```

I have mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar in my classpath.

Part of stack trace is given below:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException: Failed to load cache:
>   DepartmentsCache
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: classorg.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed
>   to load cache
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired
>   from the underlying database!
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException:
>   A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory
>   or source.  ... Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   ...
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>
> ... ...

I am not sure why it cannot find the driver. I tried many methods and was not able to make any progress.

Comment: How do you check that the MySQL driver is in the classpath? Where do you put it? How do you start the Ignite node?

Comment: I tried two ways; 1) in run as configurations, I selected the classpath tab and chose the connector jar under "user entries" 2) uses -cp as a programargument and pointed to the driver jar. The ignite node was started using ServerNodeCodeStartup, which was created as part of importing the model. i can see that server is started correctly and I can view the caches etc. using the ignite web console.

Comment: Can you share the generated project with us so that we could take a look?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The issue resolved. I had set the classpath with loadCache class. I thought the client is the one connecting and loading the caches. As soon as I set the classpath on the serverNodeStartup class, it worked like a champ. Thanks.